# Backbone - accessing in jsfiddle console

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jsfiddle

I'm working with the event system and I wanted to run some quick commands in the console.

I noticed the global variable Backbone is available in the JavaScript window of www.jsfiddle.net but not from the console.

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ezj2r/1/)

```
console.log('hello');
console.log(Backbone);
```

This is different behavior from what I'm use to.

When I type Backbone into the console ( I am in FF 14 ) I get:

`ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined`

Comment: +1 for your awesome username

Comment: Also, it works by the way, see http://jsfiddle.net/ezj2r/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the joy of iframes (or frames in general). Chances are good that the console panel you had was attached to the parent site and not to the iframe containing your code (and thus the `Backbone` object)

Comment: Note that you can select the target frame in Chrome dev console.

Comment: @rlemon: That shouldn't matter at all. `Backbone` comes from a `<script src=...>` and thus the scope of the onload function doesn't matter.

Comment: @ThiefMaster alas, looks like it worked regardless in Chrome. I spoke too soon.